# How to evaluate this function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

I am trying to use the below Excel formula in my VBA code but can't get it to work:

=Rows(Unique(Filter(myRange, myRange))

This function works as expected in Excel, and the range I am using is a column from a table (also working as expected). Not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

```
Dim ldRng As Range
Dim ans As Variant
Set ldRng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TimeTable").ListColumns("Load ID").DataBodyRange
                             
With Application
    ans = .Rows(.Unique(.Filter(ldRng, ldRng)))
End With
                              
If ans = 2 Then
                                
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = mi.ReceivedTime
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Replace(fName, ".pdf", ext, 1)
                
End If
```

I am getting a mismatch error on the "ans =" line.

Comment: You're using the late-bound version of `WorksheetFunction.Unique` and `WorksheetFunction.Filter`. There's no such thing as `WorksheetFunction.Rows` though. [`Application.Rows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.rows) is very different.

Comment: If you want to evaluate that formula, then use `ActiveSheet.Evaluate`.

Comment: @BigBen I changed the code to the below and am still receiving an error. Is it the syntax?                                                                                                                                    
                    ans = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("Rows(Unique(Filter(ldRng, ldRng)))")
Its error 2029

Comment: Inside the `Evaluate`, pass the exact formula you used in the worksheet.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the unique count here? If so, no need for FILTER at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only numbers and empty cells in this `Load ID` column you can use the code:

```
   Dim ldRng As Range
   Dim ans As Variant
   Set ldRng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TimeTable").ListColumns("Load ID").DataBodyRange
   With Application
      ans = UBound(.Unique(.Filter(ldRng, ldRng)))
   End With
 '  Debug.Print ans
```